# Binding problems using Spring MVC

Tags: java, data-binding, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 3.1 to develop a Java web app.  I have a JSP that has two paired radio buttons, an entry field, and a dropdown select box.  I need these values to be available to my mapped controller, via a model class' fields.

The security and URL mapping works fine, as I've seen in debugger before.  The issue is that when I tried to get the JSP data values populating my model, I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'cccForm' available as request attribute
```

Here is part of my JSP:

```
<c:url var="cccUrl" value="/registers/default/ccPreauth/authorize" />
    <div class="mainWrapper">
    <form:form id="cccForm" action="${cccUrl}" method="post" modelAttribute="cccForm">
  ...
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Select an option.</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="field-input">
                    <form:radiobutton id="paymentOption" path="paymentOption" value="authorizeCC" />
                    Collect Credit Card Information
                </div>
                <div class="field-input">
                    Authorization Amount $
                    <form:input path="authAmount" maxlength="10" size="10" class="extendWidth"/> 
                    <span class="instructions">
                        <spring:message code="label.authorization.note" />
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="field-input">
                    <form:radiobutton id="paymentOption" path="paymentOption" value="cancelAuth" />
                    Choose a Reason and Cancel Credit Card Collection
                </div>
                <div class="field-input right">
                    <form:select id="selectedReason" path="selectedReason" >
                        <c:forEach items="${reasonList}" var="reason">
                            <option value=${reason.reasonText}>${reason.reasonText}</option>
                            <br />
                        </c:forEach>
                    </form:select>
                </div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="right">
<button class="btnBlue" id="submitButton" type="submit">
```

Here is part of my controller:

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/registers/default/ccPreauth")
@SessionAttributes(ControllerConstants.DEFAULT_REGISTER_ATTR_NM)
public class CCCaptureController {

...
    @RequestMapping(value="/authorize" )
public ModelAndView authorize(
         final Authentication auth,
         final @ModelAttribute("ccCapturePaymentRequest") CCCapturePaymentForm ccCapturePaymentRequest,
         final BindingResult result,
         final HttpServletResponse response) {

      final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(CC_PREAUTH_PAYMENT_VIEW);

      return mav;
}
```

and finally, here is my model class:

```
    public class CCCapturePaymentForm implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6839171190322687142L;
    @NumberFormat(style = Style.CURRENCY)
    private BigDecimal  authAmount;
    private String      selectedReason;
    private String      paymentOption;

    public BigDecimal getAuthAmount() {
        return authAmount;
    }

    public void setAuthAmount(BigDecimal authAmount) {
        this.authAmount = authAmount;
    }

    public String getSelectedReason() {
        return selectedReason;
    }

    public void setSelectedReason(String selectedReason) {
        this.selectedReason = selectedReason;
    }

    public String getPaymentOption() {
        return paymentOption;
    }

    public void setPaymentOption(String paymentOption) {
        this.paymentOption = paymentOption;
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to get this to work correctly?  Please don't stop at just the reason for the exception above - please verify and correct my code as I am on a tight schedule as usual and have little experience with Spring MVC.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for those Spring MVC newbies...

I had to set the "cccForm" to a new instance of my next page's form inside the controller search method (that then tries to being up the page that was getting the error).

In a nutshell: I had to set the empty backing bean value in the preceding controller method so that the follow-on method and JSP page have it to work with.

Hope this helps someone else avoid my mistake.
Mark

Answer (score 2):

You have this in your form:

```
modelAttribute="cccForm"
```

So you should have this in your controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("cccForm") CCCapturePaymentForm ccCapturePaymentRequest
```

That's how you bind the form backing object with the model attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I tried changing this, but got the same error. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, and I can not reproduce from your code since there's stuff missing: constants, closing </form:form> tag, etc. Try posting a smaller compile-safe version of your code.

Comment: Extending Betoverse answer: Use `@ModelAttribute("cccForm") CCCapturePaymentForm cccForm`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I got the same error.  Seems like maybe it's due to mapping to backing bean?  What is correct way for radio buttons and select choices?